# How to use DexGuard in java project whith Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, dexguard

I am trying to use DexGuard plugin in Java project whith Gradle. It is library project for android.

But i want to link DexGuard library whitout:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Because I need to use:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Is it possible to use DexGuard plugin such a way?

I need this way to use because i need to use an additional plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

And I have a problem to use this plugin in conjunction whith android plugin...

My gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        jcenter()
        flatDir dirs: 'DexGuard/lib'
    }
}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.2'
        classpath ':dexguard'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.jar')
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
    }
}

shadowJar {
...
}

task sdkDexguard(type: com.saikoa.dexguard.gradle.DexGuardTask) {
    configuration 'dexguard.txt'
    injars  'build/classes'
    injars  'libs'
    outjars 'build/application.apk'
}
```

I can not to build tasklist. Error in line task sdkDexguard:

```
Could not find property 'com' on root project
```

**UPD**
Problem in the library DexGuard 6.1.11 for standalone usage. GuardSquare team will solve that soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved in version 7.0.31. Now possible to use this method for standalone usage.